# initiatorname.iscsi is overwritten

Tags: redhat, iscsi, rhel8

I use RHEL 8.8 on my machines.
I run the following command:

```bash
echo InitiatorName=$(/sbin/iscsi-iname) > /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
```

It sets correctly the name. But after some time file is set to default. Something is overwriting this file. Do you know how to block that?